# Preview an uploaded file that is stored in database

Tags: javascript, python, file, pyramid

I have a database with text files, images, etc. Now I want to preview them in another process(not part of the upload page or proceess). What tool could/would I use for this, and/or how?

In my research I have found a list of libraries, but I cant see how the libraries can be used to open/preview the file directly from the database(with out downloading the file).

I am working on a web application using pyramid(python).
In my research, I found:

- [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html)
- [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html)

In the above mentioned libs, as far as I can understand, the file has to be local, i.e. on the computer or device you are using or is there a way to use these libs?.

I have also looked at possible JavaScript or jQuery packages to do this, though the only packages I can find is to deal with uploading.

I have code to download the file:

```
@view_config(name="get_compliance_document", permission="compliance_admin")
def compliance_document(self, rid=None, filename=None):
    doc_id = self.request.subpath[0]
    if doc_id and ComplianceDocument.by_id(doc_id):
        compliance_file_id = ComplianceDocument.by_id(
            doc_id).document_file_id
        compliance_file = Files.by_id(compliance_file_id)

        f = StringIO.StringIO(compliance_file.data)
        return Response(
            content_type=str(compliance_file.type),
            content_disposition="attachment; filename=" +
            str(compliance_file.name),
            content_length=compliance_file.size,
            app_iter=FileIter(f, compliance_file.size)
        )
    raise HTTPNotFound()
```

Is there perhaps a way I can use `Response` to preview the file?

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: You don't want to download them, you want to output them in html page(s). For images use `<img>` tag and text can be put into any html content tag. Very standard for any dynamic content web page

Comment: @charlietfl using the `<img>` tag to display images work, but I am not familiar with the `<content>` tag... I will research it a bit and alternatives.. thank you.

Comment: Any content tag ... `<p>` .. `<div>`.etc. A `<pre>` tag will show line breaks...or use css in other tags or replace `\n` with `<br>` before sending to browser